# Sequence of Continuous Functions converging pointwise

Tags: calculus, continuity, sequence-of-function

Basically, I'm wondering if the following function (defined over all the reals) is continuous:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$

The graph seems to be continuous, but I can't think of any way to prove that the sum itself is continuous.

Edit: Is there a way to do so with the M-test because I haven't covered Hyperbolic Identities

Comment: By M-test the series converges uniformly. Hence the sum is continuous.

Comment: An alternative way would be to prove that

$$f(x) = \frac{1 + \pi x \mathrm{coth}(x \pi)}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

per an identity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Rational_functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT.**
Consider the Weierstrass product for the $\sinh$ function:
$$
\frac{\sinh z}{z}=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)
$$
then take logarithmic derivatives of both sides. We get
$$
\coth z-\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2z}{z^2+\pi^2 n^2}
$$
By some easy substitutions, we have
$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{\pi  \coth (\pi  x)}{x}\right)
$$

Can you continue from here?

---

To use **M-test**, we have
$$
\frac{1}{n^2+x^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It's my pleasure :D

Answer (score 0):

Put $$f_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$$.

By Weierstrass criterion for uniform convergence we have that $f_N(x)$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ because $\frac{1}{n^2+x^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$.

We know that $f_N(x)$, $N \ge 1$, are continuous. It follows from the uniform convergence that their limit $\lim_N f_N(x)$ is also continuous, q.e.d.